# How to get microphone data in Monotouch without capturing or recording

Tags: c#, ios, audio, xamarin.ios, monogame

Using Monotouch I am wanting to access the microphone data so I can use it in a game I am working on.  I have seen the examples for recording audio and for capturing media but my desire is not to save this data only to use it to power aspects of my game.  Any examples of how this could be done would be appreciated.  My guess is that this is possible but needs to be done at a lower level than those other approaches allow. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a difference; you have to *capture* the microphone data to do *anything* with it, even if you're just capturing (i.e. "sampling") one byte at a time.

Comment: Yeah capturing means using the microphone to listen for sound.  You will need to do that.

Comment: alright thanks, will post back if successful.